# Unable to Login Django Admin after Update : Giving Error Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am encountering the error `Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed` when trying to login into the Django Admin after updating the version of Django.
Also, there were no changes in the settings of Django.

The error can be seen in the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Already posted it on https://shriekdj.hashnode.dev/unable-to-login-django-admin-after-update-giving-error-forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted.

This Issue can happen suddenly after updating to the newer version Of Django.

### Details

> Django Project Foundation team made some changes in security requirements for all Django Versions 4.0 and Above. They made it mandatory to create a list of URLs getting any type of form upload or POST request in project settings named as **CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS**.

> > They did not update the details in the latest tutorial documentation, but they published the Changes Notes at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0.

---

### First Solution

> For `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

> > Goto `settings.py` of your Django project and create a new list of URLs at last like given below

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://*', 'https://*']
```

> if You're running a project in localhost, then you should open all URLs here `*` symbol means all URLs. Also, `http://` is mandatory.

---

### Second Solution

> This is also for Localhost and `DEBUG=True`.

> > Copy the list of ALLOWED_ORIGINS into CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS as given below.

```py
ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://*', 'https://*']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ALLOWED_ORIGINS.copy()
```

---

### Third Solution

When deploying, you have to add URLs to allow form uploading ( making any POST request ).

I know this may be tricky and time-consuming but it's now mandatory.

Also, this is mandatory for Online IDEs also like Replit and Glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Open the config file (most likely `settings.py`) and set the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` key as a shallow copy of the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` key which, in turn, should be set as recommended in the documentation.<sup>1</sup>

For example:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# For security consideration, please set to match the host/domain of your site, e.g., ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com'].
# Please refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts for details.
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.yourdomain.com', '.localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']

# Whether to use a secure cookie for the CSRF cookie
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

# The value of the SameSite flag on the CSRF cookie
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-samesite
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ALLOWED_HOSTS.copy()

(...)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The config file contains a link to the documentation of the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` key — right above that key. Surprise, surprise.